# Highlight search result string case issue

Tags: javascript, regex, coldfusion, highlight, cfml

I am using a cfscript that takes in a string, search terms, and optional highlight option and return the string with search terms highlighted:

```
<cfscript>
string function highlightKeywords(required string str, required string keywords, struct highlight){
    var keyword     = "";
    var replacement = "";

    param name="highlight.tag"          default="span";
    param name="highlight.attributes"   default="style='color:rgb(255,102,0);'";

    for (var index=1; index <= listLen( arguments.keywords, " " ); index++){
        keyword = ReReplace(listGetAt(arguments.keywords, index, " "), "\(|\)", "", "all" );
        replacement = "<#highlight.tag#";
        if (len(highlight.attributes)){
            replacement &= " #highlight.attributes#";
        }
        replacement &= ">" & keyword & "</#highlight.tag#>";

        arguments.str = reReplaceNoCase( arguments.str, "\b#keyword#\b", replacement, "all" );
    }
    return arguments.str;
}
</cfscript>
```

Everything seems to be working fine, except one issue.  It changes the case of the original string.

For example, when a user search for the term "**highlight search**" and the original string is stored as "This is a Highlight Search Testing".  One would expect that it will return "This is a **Highlight Search** Testing".  Instead it returned "This is a **highlight search** Testing".  It replaced the case with whatever the user typed instead of keeping original case.  Can someone assist me in this?  Thanks in advance.

Additional Note:
CF works differently for backreferences.

Comment: `replacement &= ">" & keyword & "</#highlight.tag#>";` => `replacement &= ">$&</#highlight.tag#>";`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I tried it but it does not work.  The highlighted word became '$&'.  I got 'This is **$&** Testing'

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I am sorry but I don't understand what you mean. Can you add as a solution?

Comment: It looks like CF regex does not support `$n` [backreference syntax](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7e91.html), and I am not sure if `\0` works at all. So, you need to wrap the keyword and then use `\1` backreference in the replacement pattern.

Comment: Try `replacement &= ">\1</#highlight.tag#>"` and then `reReplaceNoCase( arguments.str, "\b(#keyword#)\b", replacement, "all" )`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew That did the trick..Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may *capture* the keyword with `"\b(#keyword#)\b"` (note the capturing parentheses) and replace with the `\1` backreference to this Group 1 value to actually replace with the matched variant of the keyword.

Use

```
replacement &= ">\1</#highlight.tag#>"
```

and then

```
 arguments.str = reReplaceNoCase( arguments.str, "\b(#keyword#)\b", replacement, "all" )
```